# Downloading the info of a QGIS WMS Url for reading it as a spreadsheet file

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs

I've recently started using QGIS and learned how to connect my map to a server through a WMS connection. Is there a way to download this data as a more "spreadsheet-like" way?

The URL is:
http://acervofundiario.incra.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?tema=imoveiscertificados_privado_go

Answer (score 2):

A WMS is simply a picture of the data, to access the individual features (what we call the geometry and attributes) you need a WFS. The organisation you are accessing my provide details of their WFS service, but I don't speak portuguese and I hate trawling through government web sites in any language so I guessed that this would work.

```
http://acervofundiario.incra.gov.br/i3geo/ogc.php?tema=imoveiscertificados_privado_go&service=WFS&request=getCapabilities
```

and while in my browser it gave an error about redefining Attribute xmlns I tried it in QGIS by adding a new WFS connection.

This works and I can see the points on my map.

[image]

and if I open the attributes table I can see all the attributes of those features:

[image]